# memory leak with UITableViewDataSource data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Hi i have found a problem with my DataSource of my UITableView.
Each time i try to fill the NSMutableArrayData in the method "addDataSection", the whole data-Array is set to the current Names-Array.

It all seems to work, until i write the Names into the Array and invoke [Names removeAllObjects]. Even in the method "addDataSection" my Names Array seems to be correct,
so i maybe have a problem with a memory leak?

This ist the Implementation of the init method in the datasource-object (calls addDataSection):

-> watch the code below

has anyone ever seen problems like this occur in objective c?

Comment: What are you trying with
[Names init];  ????

Answer (score 1):

There are tons of leaks in your code.  Here are some:

- tempNames
- currentPhoneNumber
- currentEmail
- tempDict

Also

```
[Names init];
```

**Never ever send init to an object except straight after alloc.**

Answer (score 0):

You don't release tempDict.

And as says Ahmet, what is the [Names init] ?

Comment: ok but thats not the problem at all, even if i release it i have those problems.

Comment: Name should be an argument for addDataSectionWithCategory. The problem is that Names is added to your dictionary, but after, you remove all objects. Names in not copied.

Comment: Instead on [Names removeAllObjects]; you should make Names = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];